# activity works fine when i called method directly but gives fatal exception when try to call that method through button click

Tags: android, android-intent

This is the method am trying to initiate that method through button click. what am trying to do is to give information from user interface and create XMl this method creates xml document , you can see the fields addcity addname addstate all these are given staticly now am trying to given them to edittext and pass that string to respective fields, am confused to how to do it, I tried to do this CCD_produce as a service, but couldnt understand how can that service run independently from activity and take values from UI (which is again activity) any ideas ??
         public  void CCD_Produce() {

```
    //create a CCD document and save it to a file
    CCDPackage.eINSTANCE.eClass();


ContinuityOfCareDocument ccdDocument =
    CCDFactory.eINSTANCE.createContinuityOfCareDocument().init();


PatientRole patientRole = CDAFactory.eINSTANCE.createPatientRole();
ccdDocument.addPatientRole(patientRole);
II id = DatatypesFactory.eINSTANCE.createII();
patientRole.getIds().add(id);
id.setRoot("996-756-495");
id.setExtension("2.16.840.1.113883.19.5");

// create an address object and add it to patient role
AD addr = DatatypesFactory.eINSTANCE.createAD();
patientRole.getAddrs().add(addr);
addr.getUses().add(PostalAddressUse.H);
addr.addStreetAddressLine("raleigh lane 1049");
addr.addCity("noroflkva");
addr.addState("VA");
addr.addPostalCode("23500");
 StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
buffer.append("<table border=\"1\" width=\"100%\">");
buffer.append("<thead>");
buffer.append("<tr>");`
buffer.append("<th>Substance</th>");
buffer.append("<th>Reaction</th>");
buffer.append("<th>Status</th>");
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

noClassDefinitionFound means your class path is messed up in some way. If that button is mean to start another activity, it's possible your activity isn't defined in your manifest. Making it not appear in the class path.